# Push notifications of Microsoft Edge 104 broken

Tags: google-chrome, browser, microsoft-edge, notifications

I use this site as an example
https://www.bennish.net/web-notifications.html

In Chrome and old versions of Edge, the notifications will look like this:

[image]

The title is Chrome and the bottom shows the website.

But in Edge, the notifications look like this:

[image]

The title is the website and the bottom says "via Microsoft Edge".

As a result, the website will be shown in Notifications setting panel like a single app:
[image]

What's worse, when I click the notifications to open the site, the URL will look like this:

[image]

A very strange URL and cannot be opened at all.

And a Twitter Notification will look like this

```
http://0%7C0%7Cdefault%7C0%7Chttps//twitter.com/%7Cp#https://twitter.com/#1tweet-1556724142673641474
```

while the actual URL is

```
https://twitter.com/imas_ml_visual/status/1556724142673641474
```

Comment: What did you click on to get the incorrect URL? When I click on the notification itself it does nothing except shows "Clicked" on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

It's a bug of Edge 104.0.1293.47 [Discussion on Microsoft Tech Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/discussions/broken-push-notification-on-edge-104-windows-10/m-p/3594566)

The solution to this problem is as follows

1. Open `edge://flags/`
2. Disable `Toast Notification Background Task Event Handlers`

Then the update of push notification will be rolled back.